# How can I view the sql access generated to create an existing table?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

If a table was created using Access, how can I look up the SQL Access generated to create that table?

Comment: Google: `site:stackoverflow.com ms-access get create table statement` - there are tools for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannon see the original SQL used to create a table, but you can see the SQL that Access generates -or could be used- to create a table.

The SQL is basically a SELECT...INTO

Create a new query, then convert the query to a 'Make Table' query, Then display the SQL with a right-click context menu.

[image]

In this example the SQL generated is:

```
   SELECT Table1.ID INTO tbl_foo
   FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I've already found this out but it offers no help with an existing table. There's no way to see the SQL that created a table?

Comment: No. Access does not keep a log or history of queries or commands  executed, if that is what you are looking for.